# Not Able To Set Dynamically Validator Inside FormGroup in FormArray - Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have one query in Angular Reactive Form.

I have below formGroup, and inside that formGroup, I have a formArray, and inside that formArray, I have another formGroup.
Here is the main formGroup

```
public formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    email: ["", Validators.required],
    address: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.initFun()
    ])
});
```

Here is the formArray initFun() function

```
fun() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
        city: [""],
        state: [""]
    });
}
```

Now the query is I want to set the validator to city and state dynamically.

What is the approach to add a dynamic validator to formArray inside formGroup?

I can set the validator to email using below syntax:

```
this.formGroup.controls["email"].setValidators(Validators.required);
```

But I am not able to set validator for the city and state inside the address array.

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

***Update***

I've created a sample of the above case you can check out here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-angular

Let me know if I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Create a method that return your email controlArray. Do a for loop over the formGroups inside the formArray and use the same method to set the validator like you are doing

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I have tried that method but it doesn't work getting error as below
Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over each group in the `fb.array` and set all the needed validators like this:

```
let groupItems = this.formGroup.controls["address"].controls;

for(let item of groupItems) {
    item.controls["city"].setValidators(...);
    item.controls["state"].setValidators(...);
}
```

**UPD**: To avoid *"Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'"* issue, use the following assignment:

```
let groupItems:any = (this.formGroup.get("address") as FormArray).controls;
```

Comment: I am getting an error as below
"Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'."

Comment: Try casting it to ``FormArray`` and use like this: ``let groupItems = <FormArray>this.formGroup.get("address")``. See more info here https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Comment: Hi Anna, Did you check that I have a formGroup of City and Country inside that formArray?
I've already tried the solution which you gave, but it doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: I have created a sample here can you please check and let me know your input.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-angular

Comment: @Burhan you are initializing your ``formGroup`` instance in wrong place, where your instance of ``FormBuilder`` is not yet accessible. You should either do it in ``constructor`` or in ``ngOnInit``. I have created a fork of your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-angular-nemtwh

Comment: Yeah, I got that I have to put the formGroup instance in the constructor but then again I am not able to get the controls of formArray.
You can check in your fork the controls is giving an error of "Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
Due to above error, the build is getting failed in my local.

Comment: The following change removes the error in sandbox ``let groupItems:any = (this.formGroup.get("address") as FormArray).controls;``. I have updated the demo, see if it fixes your local build.

Comment: Perfect. It worked in my local too. :)
Thanks a lot for the help.
Can you please update your answer so I'll mark it correct and other people can also get the proper idea. :)

Thank a lot once again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168049/discussion-between-burhan-and-anna-pohorielova).

Answer (score 1):

you can try to get the address FormArray by declaring a method that return it

```
get address(): FormArray {
  return this. formGroup.get("address") as FormArray;
}
```

after that you can use the method at to get the specific formGroup inside

```
this.address.at(index)
```

after that is just a matter of assigning the  Validator to the formControl

**UPDATED BASED ON YOUR LINK**

your code will look like

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup.controls["email"].setValidators(Validators.required);
    let groupItems = this.formGroup.get("address") as FormArray;;
    groupItems
    for(let index = 0 ; index < groupItems.length; index++ ) {
        groupItems.at(index).get("city").setValidators(Validators.required);
        groupItems.at(index).get("country").setValidators(Validators.required);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have created a sample here can you please check and let me know your input. https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-angular

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I have got the solution. You can check here for reference https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-angular
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Anna,

Here is the updated answer to my above question.
You can refer this link for the reference.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-angular

Please ask me if you have any doubts :)