# Not Able To Delele Dynamically Validator Inside FormGroup in FormArray - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, formarray, formgroups

To set the validator inside the form group in the form arrayI tried this method described in this link:

[Not Able To Set Dynamically Validator Inside FormGroup in FormArray - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610599/not-able-to-set-dynamically-validator-inside-formgroup-in-formarray-angular/75672326#75672326)

I tried this, and it worked perfectly for adding validators, but it doesn't work for deleting them.

I tried the remove validators method and the clear validators method, but they don't work.

```
// let groupItems:any = (this.formGroup.get("address") as FormArray).controls;

const groupItems: any = (address as FormArray).controls;

  for (const item of groupItems) {
    item.controls.city.clearValidators();
    item.controls.state.clearValidators();
  }
```

What is the approach to delete a dynamic validator to formArray inside formGroup?

***Update***

I tried to add `updateValueAndValidity(), but it gave me a stack error:

```
    for (const item of groupItems) 
        item.controls.city.clearValidators();
        item.controls.city.updateValueAndValidity();
        item.controls.state.clearValidators();
        item.controls.state.updateValueAndValidity();
      }
```

SO:
to avoid LoggingService: Maximum call stack size exceeded while using
I add a listener to the selector that triggers validation changes with the `take(1)` rxJS pipe and set validations like this:

```
          Selector?.valueChanges
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(SelectorRes => {
        if (SelectorRes === true) {
          const groupItems: any = (address as FormArray)
            .controls;

          for (const item of groupItems) {
            item.controls.city.setValidators(
              Validators.required
            );
            item.controls.state.setValidators(Validators.required);
          }

          //   !was
          console.log('call validation 1');
        } else if (
          SelectorRes === false
        ) {
          const groupItems: any = (address as FormArray)
            .controls;

          for (const item of groupItems) {
            item.controls.city.clearValidators();
            item.controls.city.updateValueAndValidity()
            item.controls.state.clearValidators();
            item.controls.state.updateValueAndValidity();
          }

          //   !was
          console.log('delete validation 2');
        }
      });
```

It works, but it calls too many times in one change, I think:

- (25) call validation 1 -- foo.validator.ts
- (144) delete validation 2 -- foo.validator.ts

Comment: A question, why do you want to remove the validators? Generally it's better use a custom conditional field validator

Comment: I don't understand the question: What do you mean by "conditional field validator" ?

Comment: a Custom form control that depends from another variable or another formControl (e.g. the "typical" repeat password or a "want to received by email" that make mandatory the email)

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Comment: The last link I see is [here](https://medium.com/ngx/3-ways-to-implement-conditional-validation-of-reactive-forms-c59ed6fc3325), but in SO there're multiple examples, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939157/angular-conditional-required-validator-between-two-fields)

Comment: I have a big form-service file, and I don't want to write a custom validator for some forms, which must be required in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl):

> When you add or remove a validator at run time, you must call updateValueAndValidity() for the new validation to take effect.

You can do something like this:

```
const groupItems: any = (address as FormArray).controls;

  for (const item of groupItems) {
    item.controls.city.clearValidators();
    item.controls.city.updateValueAndValidity();
    item.controls.state.clearValidators();
    item.controls.state.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

Comment: when I use item.controls.city.updateValueAndValidity();
It works but gives me an error:
LoggingService: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I tried to use it: updateValueAndValidity()
        onlySelf: true,
        emitEvent: false
      });
but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think that I need parent (main form Group) to be validated too, but I can't think of doing it without
onlySelf: false